# Literal difference between table, schema, tablespace and user

Tags: oracle

What is the literal difference between **table, schema, tablespace** and **user**?

Comment: See the [Oracle Concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/intro.htm#CNCPT940).

Comment: These are not PL/SQL concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Database :** Collection of data is called database.

**Tablespace :** An Oracle Database consists of one or more logical storage units called tablespace, which collectively use to store all the database's data.  Each tablespace in an Oracle Database consists of one or more datafiles which are used to store data physically.

**Schema :** A schema is collection of database objects, including logical structures such as tables, views, sequences, stored procedures, synonyms, indexes, clusters, triggers, and links.

**User :** A user owns a schema. A user and a schema have the same name. In Oracle, users and schemas are essentially the same thing. You can consider that a user is the account you use to connect to a database, and a schema is the set of objects (tables, views, etc.) that belong to that account. The CREATE USER command creates a user. It also automatically creates a schema for that user.

**Table :** Tables are the basic unit of data storage in an Oracle Database. Data is stored in rows and columns.

For all intents and purposes you can consider a user to be a schema and a schema to be a user. A user can access objects in schemas other than their own, if they have permission to do so.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer.
Can you expand on the relation between a Schema and a Tablespace?
Can one schema have objects in to different tablespaces?
Can a Tablespace hold multiple schemas?